# What's the oral address of "fellow student"?

Tags: expressions, british-english, politeness, expression-choice

I have known "fellow student" is a formal address and we used this in somewhere formally. But in oral situation, how to introduce a senior student to my friends when we face to face? If I say "this is my fellow student Alan", is that too weird?

I am so sorry not provide detailed situation. I mean in University in UK, casual situation let's say during a lunch, my friends and me meet a fellow student "ABCD". "ABCD" knows me but don't know my friends and I need to introduce them to each other.

Comment: You don't provide any context in your question that would make it possible to supply a satisfactory answer. What age are the students? What kind of occasion are they being introduced at? What kind of educational institution is it? Are we talking about male or female students, or both sexes? Which country are we talking about? And so on.

Comment: I am so sorry not provide detailed situation. I mean in University in UK, casual situation let's say during a lunch, my friends and me meet a fellow student "ABCD". "ABCD" knows me but don't know my friends and I need to introduce them to each other. Would you please to teach me how to introduce "ABCD" for both sexes?

Comment: 'This is Alan, a fellow student of mine'. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If this were high/secondary school, then *"This is my classmate, Alan"* would be fine, if you're sharing accommodations you could say: *"This is my roommate, Alan"*. Otherwise it's simply: *"Bob, this is Alan. Alan this is Bob, he's a friend of mine (etc.)"*

Answer (score 3):

Introductions among young people tend to be fairly informal, simply "Ken, this is Alan*, or even "Ken ... Alan". The normal assumption at a university would be that anybody you introduced would be a fellow student, so there would be no need to mention this. If you thought it might be interesting, you might add some information such as "He's in my Shakespeare class".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with that it's a normal assumption at university but how to emphasize Alan is more senior than me but not only mention the name (I'm not freshman)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you're an undergrad, you might want to say, "this is Alan, he's a grad student here, but other than that....

Comment: Informal introductions are the norm period.

Comment: Why would you need to emphasise this? I suppose you could say, "He's a year ahead of me," or similar.

Comment: @RoryAlsop The OP may come from a culture where such kowtowing is the norm, and he may not understand that it will not be well received here.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see wrong with the introduction you propose if Alan is more than a fellow student, in which case you might use a different appellation: "friend", perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

How about the word **[colleague](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/colleague)**?
Dictionary.com defines **colleague** as *an associate*.

While the word is normally used in the context of the workplace, I have heard it used applied to schooling.

Answer (score 0):

Some people probably consider it a little bit primary-school-ish, but I'd say **classmate**.